# ATR Targets/Stops are never hit

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying add *ATR Targets & Stop* and custom *position sizing* for each trade. There are x3 Targets (TP1, TP2, TP3 - the gray lines), and the "EXIT BUY" order should split the position size evenly between the targets.

The issue is that targets are never hit that could be because ATR changes on each candle. But when it is specified in `strategy.exit` shouldn't it remain the same? How do I solve it?
Is `strategy.position_size` all I need to change for custom position sizing e.g. custom risk management?

[image]

```
//@version=5
strategy("Test Strategy", overlay = true)

// ———————————————————— Inputs {
atrLengthInput = input.int(14, "ATR Length")
slAtrMultiplierInput = input.float(1.5, "SL ATR Multiplier", step = 0.1)
tp1AtrMultiplierInput = input.float(1.5, "TP1 ATR Multiplier", step = 0.1)
tp2AtrMultiplierInput = input.float(2.5, "TP2 ATR Multiplier", step = 0.1)
tp3AtrMultiplierInput = input.float(3.5, "TP3 ATR Multiplier", step = 0.1)
// }

// ———————————————————— Calculations {
atr = ta.atr(14)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))

long_sl = close - atr * slAtrMultiplierInput
long_tp1 = close + atr * tp1AtrMultiplierInput
long_tp2 = close + atr * tp2AtrMultiplierInput
long_tp3 = close + atr * tp3AtrMultiplierInput

short_sl = close + atr * slAtrMultiplierInput
short_tp1 = close - atr * tp1AtrMultiplierInput
short_tp2 = close - atr * tp2AtrMultiplierInput
short_tp3 = close - atr * tp3AtrMultiplierInput
// }

// ———————————————————— Plots {
plot(long_sl, color = color.red)
plot(long_tp1, color = color.gray)
plot(long_tp2, color = color.gray)
plot(long_tp3, color = color.gray)
// }

// ———————————————————— Strategy calls {
strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, when = longCondition)
strategy.exit("BUY", "EXIT BUY", stop = long_sl, limit = long_tp1)

strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, when = shortCondition)
strategy.exit("SELL", "EXIT SELL", stop = short_sl, limit = short_tp1)
// }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close here, there are just a few things we need to do in Pine to make this work. First off we need to declare these stops with "var". This allows us to "set and save" a variable, which prevents them from recalculating on each bar as your main problem describes.

Next, we need to init these under an if to assign them. I used your entry conditions and checked that we weren't in a pos already (otherwise we would re-init our stops/limits)

Also, we need to use a positional reference when= in our exits, so I added that to the strategy.exit calls.

The second variable in the exit call is "from entry" which we need to match to our entry tag. If we only have the one entry type per bias we could forgo this arg, but I left it in to show the proper trade identifier. Lastly I added some line break style plots making color na if not in a position so we don't see see anything we don't need to see, and the lines can break between value assignments.

Take note of the var def with "=" and the assignment with := as well under the ifs. This is how you can assign new values conditionally to a variable already defined in Pine. Here is the edited code to compare.

Cheers and all the best,

Bjorgum

```
//@version=5
strategy("Test Strategy", overlay = true)

// ———————————————————— Inputs {
atrLengthInput        = input.int  (14,  "ATR Length")
slAtrMultiplierInput  = input.float(1.5, "SL ATR Multiplier",  step = 0.1)
tp1AtrMultiplierInput = input.float(1.5, "TP1 ATR Multiplier", step = 0.1)
tp2AtrMultiplierInput = input.float(2.5, "TP2 ATR Multiplier", step = 0.1)
tp3AtrMultiplierInput = input.float(3.5, "TP3 ATR Multiplier", step = 0.1)
// }

// ———————————————————— Calculations {

FLAT  = strategy.position_size == 0
LONG  = strategy.position_size > 0
SHORT = strategy.position_size < 0

var long_sl   = 0.0
var long_tp1  = 0.0
var long_tp2  = 0.0
var long_tp3  = 0.0

var short_sl  = 0.0
var short_tp1 = 0.0
var short_tp2 = 0.0
var short_tp3 = 0.0

atr = ta.atr(14)

longCondition  = ta.crossover (ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))

if (FLAT or SHORT) and longCondition
    long_sl   := close - atr * slAtrMultiplierInput
    long_tp1  := close + atr * tp1AtrMultiplierInput
    long_tp2  := close + atr * tp2AtrMultiplierInput
    long_tp3  := close + atr * tp3AtrMultiplierInput

if (FLAT or LONG) and shortCondition
    short_sl  := close + atr * slAtrMultiplierInput
    short_tp1 := close - atr * tp1AtrMultiplierInput
    short_tp2 := close - atr * tp2AtrMultiplierInput
    short_tp3 := close - atr * tp3AtrMultiplierInput
// }

// ———————————————————— Plots {
plot(LONG  ? long_sl   : na, color = color.red  , style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(LONG  ? long_tp1  : na, color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(LONG  ? long_tp2  : na, color = color.gray , style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(LONG  ? long_tp3  : na, color = color.gray , style=plot.style_linebr)

plot(SHORT ? short_sl  : na, color = color.red  , style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(SHORT ? short_tp1 : na, color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(SHORT ? short_tp2 : na, color = color.gray , style=plot.style_linebr)
plot(SHORT ? short_tp3 : na, color = color.gray , style=plot.style_linebr)
// }

// ———————————————————— Strategy calls {
strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long,   when = longCondition)
strategy.exit ("Long Exit", "BUY",     when = LONG,  stop = long_sl,  limit = long_tp1)

strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, when = shortCondition)
strategy.exit ("Short Exit", "SELL",   when = SHORT, stop = short_sl, limit = short_tp1)
// }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 1) I see that the orders are triggered in the beginning of the next candle instead in the middle of the current candle where TP1 was hit. Is there any way to change that behavior? 2) Is there a such option to split the equity evenly between TP1, TP2 and TP3 instead of selling everything at TP1?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, the orders are performed as expected. My bad! The second question remains tho. How do I split the position between TP1, TP2 and TP3?

Comment: You can look into pyramiding. It’s a setting we can put in the strategy() line. If you run into trouble it’s likely best to post a new Q. Best of luck and take care my friend !!

Comment: oh! one entry and multiple exits - you need to look into the qty= arg of the strategy .exit call. There is an arg for percent too, so you could choose how much to scale out on each. Pyramiding is for multiple entries, I apologize