# Why doesn't my SL get executed, how to set break-even + trail stop?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Sitting hours here to get an SL with break-even after first taget is hit and start auto trailing after second target. I let it plot the slLevel, which behaves properly but the strategy doesn't execute the SL when the price touches the line.

This is my code:

```
shortSL := if strategy.position_size == -3
    slFromEntry
else if strategy.position_size == -2
    strategy.position_avg_price - stopOffset
else if strategy.position_size == -1
    shortStopPrice
else
    shortStopPrice

if (shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    slFromEntry :=  shortSL
    strategy.entry('Short1', strategy.short, qty=3, stop=shortEntryPrice) //, when = shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    strategy.exit('TP1', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP1", limit=tp1Short)
    strategy.exit('TP2', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP2", limit=tp2Short)
    strategy.exit('TP3', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP3", limit=tp3Short)
strategy.exit('SL', 'Short1', qty=3, comment_loss="SL", stop=shortSL)
```

I experimented a lot and this version gets the SL set break-even and assumingly trailed, but it now it doesn't get the targets right anymore, although I didn't change anything else of the rest.

```
shortSL := if strategy.position_size == -3
    slFromEntry
else if strategy.position_size == -2
    strategy.position_avg_price - stopOffset
else if strategy.position_size == -1
    shortStopPrice
else
    shortStopPrice

if (shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    slFromEntry :=  shortSL
    strategy.entry('Short1', strategy.short, qty=3, stop=shortEntryPrice) //, when = shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    strategy.exit('TP1', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP1", comment_loss="SL",limit=tp1Short, stop=shortSL)
    strategy.exit('TP2', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP2", comment_loss="SL",limit=tp2Short, stop=shortSL)
    strategy.exit('TP3', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP3", comment_loss="SL",limit=tp3Short, stop=shortSL)
strategy.exit('SLS1', 'Short1', qty=3, comment_loss="SL", stop=shortSL)
```

Every way I do it, either the targets work or the SL. Where is the flaw?

I tried the above code and many variants

Answer (score 1):

Eventually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521463/atr-targets-stops-are-never-hit?rq=2) post gave me the idea that the problem is, that readjusting strategy.exit will readjust both, SL and TP. Therefore I came up with the following. After days, it works.

```
if (shortCondition and strategy.position_size >= 0)
    slFromEntry :=  shortSL
    tp1Short := low[bar_ref] - (low[bar_ref] *  tp1Percent / 100)
    tp2Short := low[bar_ref] - (low[bar_ref] *  tp2Percent / 100)
    tp3Short := low[bar_ref] - (low[bar_ref] *  tp3Percent / 100)
    strategy.entry('Short1', strategy.short, qty=3, stop=shortEntryPrice)
if inShort and strategy.position_size == -3
    strategy.exit('TP1', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP1", comment_loss="SL",limit=tp1Short, stop=shortSL)
    strategy.exit('TP2', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP2", comment_loss="SL",limit=tp2Short, stop=shortSL)
    strategy.exit('TP3', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP3", comment_loss="SL",limit=tp3Short, stop=shortSL)
else if inShort and strategy.position_size == -2
    strategy.exit('TP2', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP2", comment_loss="SL",limit=tp2Short, stop=shortSL)
    strategy.exit('TP3', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP3", comment_loss="SL",limit=tp3Short, stop=shortSL) 
else if inShort and strategy.position_size == -1
    strategy.exit('TP3', 'Short1', qty=1, comment_profit="TP3", comment_loss="SL",limit=tp3Short, stop=shortSL)
```